# Why is the mesh not rendering?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I am working through a [tutorial here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/open-source-procedural-hexagon-terrain.233296/). I have [the package shared through my google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_iu5yU9Jm1bR3F5RlIxNXUzcjg/view?usp=sharing) for convenience.

I have set up a scene that looks like this:
[image: hexgrid main scene]

The subject `GameObject` is `HexGridController` and three objects that are disabled: `center_fill`, `Backdrop`, `DiagnosticDisplay`.

The grid controller is an otherwise empty GameObject except for attached script:
[image: hex grid controller properties]

...and the HexGridController script:

```
    public class HexGridController : MonoBehaviour, IGridInterface {

         public float cellWidth = 50F;
         public HexOrientation cellFacing = HexOrientation.Acute;
         public int cellCols = 20;
         public int cellRows = 14;
         public float degOffset = 0.0F;
         // ... snipped IGridInterface implementations

         // Use this for initialization
         private void Start () {
             print("Hexagonal Grid Controller started");

             print("hex vertices:");
             int idx = 0;
             foreach(var vert in vertices){
                 print(string.Format("\t[{0}]: {1}", idx, vert.ToString()));
                 ++idx;
             }
         }

         #region    HiddenInInspector: vertices, uv, triangles
         [HideInInspector]
         public static Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[]
         {
                 new Vector3(0f, Hexagon.floor, 1f),        //    north
                 new Vector3(1f, Hexagon.floor, .5f),    //    northeast
                 new Vector3(1f, Hexagon.floor, -.5f),    //    southeast
                 new Vector3(0f, Hexagon.floor, -1f),    //    south
                 new Vector3(-1f , Hexagon.floor, -.5f),    //     southwest
                 new Vector3(-1f, Hexagon.floor, .5f),    //    northwest
         };

         [HideInInspector]
         public static Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[]
         {
             new Vector2(0.5F,1),    //    north
             new Vector2(1,0.75F),    //    northeast
             new Vector2(1,0.25F),    //    southeast
             new Vector2(0.5F,0),    //    south
             new Vector2(0,0.25F),    //     southwest
             new Vector2(0,0.75F),    //    northwest
         };

         [HideInInspector]
         public static int[] triangles = new int[]
         {
             1,5,0,
             1,4,5,
             1,2,4,
             2,3,4
         };
         #endregion
     }
```

And finally, `HexGrid` is a `GameObject` with the following script attached:

```
public class Hexagon : MonoBehaviour {
     private MeshRenderer meshRenderer;

     public const float floor = 0;

     public HexGridController grid;
     public Texture texture;

     // Use this for initialization
     private void Start () {
         print("Hexagon started");

         HexGridController.vertices[0] = new Vector3((grid.cellWidth * Mathf.Cos((float)(2*Mathf.PI*(1+0.5)/6))), Hexagon.floor, (grid.cellWidth * Mathf.Sin((float)(2*Mathf.PI*(1+0.5)/6))));
         HexGridController.vertices[1] = new Vector3((grid.cellWidth * Mathf.Cos((float)(2*Mathf.PI*(0+0.5)/6))), Hexagon.floor, (grid.cellWidth * Mathf.Sin((float)(2*Mathf.PI*(0+0.5)/6))));
         HexGridController.vertices[2] = new Vector3((grid.cellWidth * Mathf.Cos((float)(2*Mathf.PI*(5+0.5)/6))), Hexagon.floor, (grid.cellWidth * Mathf.Sin((float)(2*Mathf.PI*(5+0.5)/6))));
         HexGridController.vertices[3] = new Vector3((grid.cellWidth * Mathf.Cos((float)(2*Mathf.PI*(4+0.5)/6))), Hexagon.floor, (grid.cellWidth * Mathf.Sin((float)(2*Mathf.PI*(4+0.5)/6))));
         HexGridController.vertices[4] = new Vector3((grid.cellWidth * Mathf.Cos((float)(2*Mathf.PI*(3+0.5)/6))), Hexagon.floor, (grid.cellWidth * Mathf.Sin((float)(2*Mathf.PI*(3+0.5)/6))));
         HexGridController.vertices[5] = new Vector3((grid.cellWidth * Mathf.Cos((float)(2*Mathf.PI*(2+0.5)/6))), Hexagon.floor, (grid.cellWidth * Mathf.Sin((float)(2*Mathf.PI*(2+0.5)/6))));

         SetUpMesh();
     }    

     private void SetUpMesh() {
         MeshFilter meshFilter = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
         gameObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
         meshRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();

         Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
         //vertices
         mesh.vertices = HexGridController.vertices;
         //triangles
         mesh.triangles = HexGridController.triangles;
         //UV vectors
         mesh.uv = HexGridController.uv;

         //recalc for lighting
         mesh.RecalculateNormals();

         //game object's mesh filter
         meshFilter.mesh = mesh;

         //set to null when not testing
         meshRenderer.material.mainTexture = texture; 
     }

     private void Update () 
     {

     }

     private void OnDestory()
     {
         Object.Destroy(meshRenderer.material);
     }
 }
```

**NOTE:**
For what it's worth, `Hex Facing` is the hexagonal orientation at <kbd>North</kbd> - either flat or acute (or, pointy). I intend for the north-most point to be 0 and rotate clockwise:

0 - <kbd>North</kbd>
1 - <kbd>NorthEast</kbd>
2 - <kbd>SouthEast</kbd>
3 - <kbd>South</kbd>
4 - <kbd>SouthWest</kbd>
5 - <kbd>NorthWest</kbd>

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but are you sure that you have your triangles setup correctly (meaning they are not oriented backwards in a relation to your camera) and a second one - are your triangles in a camera view frustrum?

Comment: @PavelPájaHalbich: Those aren't stupid questions. But they are questions I do not know how to answer since I am new to Unity. I am simply following the tut linked in the question. The package can also be downloaded and you can see exactly how it is set up and then you can tell me the answers to your questions ... I do not know. ;)

Comment: Well, I'm currently working with Unreal Engine and I don't have Unity installed, but the principles are the same. Since you are stuck, I would recommend you folowing: have a simple level with camera and one game object. In a script of that game object do a simple thing - try to draw a triangle. From some unity forum, I found that the triangle must be defined in a clockwise manner (https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/mesh-triangles-explanation.78564/). This is simple task to iterate quickly on. Then, when you succeed, move on to that tutorial.

Comment: But, as a (pro) tip, I would like to propose another way - generate your hexagon in some 3D tool (3DS Max, Cinema 4D, Blender, Maya, ... ) So you will have only 4 faces (triangles) instead of 6 (thus saving resources for a graphic card). Then you can create Prefab from it and attach other scripts. And finally (if it is possible) use GPU instancing. This will save a lot of GPU time, especially when using a lot of hexagonal tiles.  https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html

Comment: I have only 4 triangles.

Comment: I'm sorry, I overlooked that. Anyway, there are more approaches and using one of them depends on your requirements. So, did you succeed in creating a single triagle? If so, you should have enough knowledge to continue with that tutorial.

Comment: @PavelPájaHalbich: thanks for you help. You pointed me in a good direction and I would be willing to accept your advice with some tips/pointers as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, being that I am learning Unity I cannot explain why the differences in the API of the tutorial vs. what I found to be correct. I found several things to be incorrect and following @PavelPájaHalbich 's advice, I completed a short exercise wherein I successfully rendered a single triangle.

Now, the issues I fixed and the result ...

The HexGridController is simplified since the Hexagon provides all the specific data for `vertices` and `uv`. The data for triangles remains in HexGridController.

```
#region HiddenInInspector: vertices, uv, triangles
[HideInInspector]
public static Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[6];

[HideInInspector]
public static Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[6];

[HideInInspector]
public static int[] triangles = new int[]
{
    0,1,2,
    2,3,0,
    3,4,0,
    4,5,0,
};
#endregion
```

...next, the Hexagon class got a bit of a face-lift as I correctly ordered the `vertices` and mapped the `uv` vectors:

```
private void Start () {
    print("Hexagon started");

    //  set up vertices
    vertices[(int)HexFacing.North] = new Vector3(0F, 1F, floor);
    vertices[(int)HexFacing.NorthEeast] = new Vector3(1F, .5F, floor);
    vertices[(int)HexFacing.SouthEast] = new Vector3(1F, -.5F, floor);
    vertices[(int)HexFacing.South] = new Vector3(0F, -1F, floor);
    vertices[(int)HexFacing.SouthWest] = new Vector3(-1F, -.5F, floor);
    vertices[(int)HexFacing.NorthWest] = new Vector3(-1F, .5F, floor);

    //  set up uv
    uv[(int)HexFacing.North] = new Vector2(0.5F, 1);
    uv[(int)HexFacing.NorthEeast] = new Vector2(1, 0.75F);
    uv[(int)HexFacing.SouthEast] = new Vector2(1, 0.25F);
    uv[(int)HexFacing.South] = new Vector2(0.5F, 0);
    uv[(int)HexFacing.SouthWest] = new Vector2(0, 0.25F);
    uv[(int)HexFacing.NorthWest] = new Vector2(0, 0.75F);

    SetUpMesh();
}
```

... and finally some corrections in the `SetUpMesh()` method:

```
private void SetUpMesh() {
    MeshFilter meshFilter = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
    gameObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    meshRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();

    Mesh mesh = meshFilter.mesh; // this had been newing a mesh
    mesh.Clear();                // this hadn't been called

    //vertices
    mesh.vertices = vertices;
    //triangles
    mesh.triangles = HexGridController.triangles;
    //UV vectors
    mesh.uv = uv;

    //recalc for lighting
    mesh.RecalculateNormals();

    //game object's mesh filter
    meshFilter.mesh = mesh;

    //set to null when not testing
    meshRenderer.material.mainTexture = texture; 
}
```

Now, I opted for a triangle pattern that I hadn't seen widely used (and admittedly probably for good reason).
[image: triangulated hexagon]

All of that work to finally achieve the goal of the original tutorial:  [image: rendered hexagon]